# Short story about a winemaker being unable to pay his weather bill

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A winemaker in India is unable to pay his weather bill, due to spending the money on a wedding for one of his daughters. He ends up watering the vines by hand and making a small batch. Despite the fact that it is bad wine, it shoots up the charts and makes him a bunch of money because no one has tasted wine produced from stressed grapes in 50+ years.

I’m pretty sure I read this story in the past 5 years (2018-now). It might have been in an anthology by female authors.

Comment: Is it magic wine or set in the future?

Comment: @Adamant I don't believe anyone in the present (2022) pays a 'weather bill', so it would seem that this is set in the future.

Comment: @AakashM - I thought that they might have meant a water bill. But yes, it is a weather bill according to the answer.

Answer (score 21):

I've found it. It's [*Waiting for Rain*](https://maryrobinettekowal.com/journal/waiting-for-rain/) by Mary Robinette Kowal, from her collection *[Word Puppets](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25901253-word-puppets)*.

> Sitting at the dinner table, Bharat swirled the Shiraz in his glass
> and lifted it to his nose without interest. The Shiraz carried the
> distinctive barnyard and horsesweat odors typical of the grape. Was
> this the 2045 or the ’46 vintage? There was so little vintage
> variation since micro-climate manipulation became standard that he
> often found it hard to tell. Bharat set the glass down without tasting
> it.
>
> He pushed the dal and rice together on his plate, watching the
> consistency change as they clung to each other with moisture. It was
> like making mud from dirt and rain. But he couldn’t pay his weather
> bill, so where could he get rain?

Comment: Hi, it's great that you found it; you can make this a better answer by including a more complete description here, especially noting anything you might have misremembered.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as 'accepted' by clicking the tick on the left hand side

Comment: Which, as a self-answer, can't be done for another day and a half, but still please don't forget. :)